# Spring MVC file download controller returns garbled content

Tags: spring-mvc, download

I'm trying to write a controller to return a file for download.

At first I was coding it this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}" + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.EXPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> export(@PathVariable Long id, UriComponentsBuilder builder) throws IOException {
    String filename = rolloutExportService.getDownloadFilename();
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = rolloutExportService.export(id);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>(fileSystemResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    try {
        responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(fileSystemResource.contentLength()));
        outputStream = responseEntity.getBody().getOutputStream();
        inputStream = fileSystemResource.getInputStream();
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close(); 
    }
    return responseEntity;
}
```

But the response would be a 406 The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

With the console log saying:

```
2014-11-05 01:18:39,403 DEBUG  [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource> com.nsn.nitro.project.rest.controller.RolloutExportController.export(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation 
2014-11-05 01:18:39,403 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'NITRo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
2014-11-05 01:18:39,403 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request 
2014-11-05 01:18:39,405 DEBUG  [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally 
2014-11-05 01:18:39,405 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

And so I changed it not to return a response like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}" + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.EXPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public void export(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String filename = rolloutExportService.getDownloadFilename();
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = rolloutExportService.export(id);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(fileSystemResource.contentLength()));
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        inputStream = fileSystemResource.getInputStream();
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close(); 
    }
}
```

On both controllers, the request is the same, being typed in the Chromium browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/nitro-project-rest/rollouts/3/export
```

But the response would be garbled content displayed in the browser:
PK��îeE���������������/home/stephane/tmp/language.csv%É1
À ÐÝÃô™uìÐHˆßT‰±ØûC….oy2Èy€l
¨
V8EWc/ÏñÜªµ÷>ú£¡.J‹]@uåtmáò×PKç}:H���O���PK��îeE���������������/home/stephane/tmp/country.csvKÎOIµÎKÌMµÎÉ,.ñ/JI-âJÍ³vÍKÏIÌK±6äJ+²v+JÌKN²PK*9»¶-���-���PK��îeE���������������/home/stephane/tmp/team.csvËKÌMµNI-N.Ê,(ÉÌÏ³N.JM1\KRK2sS¹BRs¬C2RJ

With the console saying:

```
20. select team0_.id as id1_15_0_, team0_.version as version2_15_0_, team0_.creation_datetime as 
creation3_15_0_, team0_.description as descript4_15_0_, team0_.name as name5_15_0_ from team 
team0_ where team0_.id=2  
2014-11-05 01:31:29,983 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit 
2014-11-05 01:31:29,983 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@6569cc] 
2014-11-05 01:31:29,988 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@6569cc] after transaction 
2014-11-05 01:31:29,988 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2014-11-05 01:31:30,013 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'NITRo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
2014-11-05 01:31:30,013 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request 
2014-11-05 01:31:30,021 DEBUG  [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally 
2014-11-05 01:31:30,021 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

My last attempt was this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}" + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.EXPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource export(@PathVariable Long id) throws IOException {
    String filename = rolloutExportService.getDownloadFilename();
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = rolloutExportService.export(id);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(fileSystemResource.contentLength()));
    responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip");
    return fileSystemResource;
}
```

But it also gave me a 406 response.

From the last attempt above, I removed the attribute: produces =

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
```

And the same request sent by the browser (seen in the console) looked like:

```
Request URL:data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC4AAAAuCAQAAAD9sOO8AAAASUlEQVR4Xu3SMQoAIAzFUO/o/c+iY4fSSfgQyesgOESHrs9I0j7TEOL9pk5i/OmB/s9IvAYQH6DjxmtTWPEWBcS52zJPIJ4lSRfUZeB1c/cgSwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
```

With the server console log saying:

```
2014-11-05 12:08:35,938 DEBUG  [ExceptionsHandler] org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
```

Comment: what type of files are you trying to download ?

Comment: In your first example there's no need to copy the stream.

Comment: @zeroflagL I saw that earlier today, indeed it was redundant. I then tried without it but got the same 406. I edited the question and posted the controller as my third attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct MIME type of the file in your controller.

If your file is a pdf:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

If your file is a gif image:

```
response.setContentType("image/gif");
```

If your file is a zip file:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
```

You may find the correct MIME type [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Comment: Why do I need to set the file mime type ? It is a zip file. I would prefer for it to be type agnostic.

Comment: Well, you need to instruct the system the file (MIME) type in order to handle it properly, otherwise it will assume some defaults and it may be OK for some file types and not OK for others.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the content Type of the HttpResponse like the following :

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
```

or set the [ContentType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#CONTENT_TYPE) using the  [HttpHeaders](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) , and set the CONTENT_ENCODING to UTF-8  like the following :

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip");
responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

so the browser will know what kind of files he is expecting, please refer to this tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_header_fields.htm) that explains the Http Headers .

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}" + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.EXPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doDownload(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String filename = rolloutExportService.export(id);
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    File downloadFile = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filename);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        mimeType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.getType();
    }
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, headerValue);
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Sending the request

```
http://localhost:8080/nitro-project-rest/rollouts/3/expor
```

in the browser pops up a download window.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
```

as will push out generic binary content. If you want the content sent from the filename extension then in your spring XML file put

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
```

and

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean" />
```